# How do I pass data back to an activity that starts the activity which passes data to it?

Tags: android

My Main Activity starts the Login Activity: Right after the setContentView, thats where I placed the intent that starts the login Activity.  Once the user enters the right credentials, the server send back data that has to be used through the app. This data is sent as a JSONResponse, here is the code

```
 Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    final JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                    if (success) {
                        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                                new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        onLoginSuccess();
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }, 3000);
```

As you can see, once the login is successful the onLoginSuccess() class is called. This is how the code of the class looks like.

```
public  void onLoginSuccess() {
        _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
        finish();

    }
```

As you can this basically just finishes and starts the main activity. How do I send the data that is in the json Response to the main activity. I can modify the initial lines of code and have the main activity started there, which would mean that i would extract the data in that class and just inject into the intent that starts the main activity, however I prefer maintaining the integrity of the code as I have written it and just using classes or methods.

As you can this basically just finishes and starts the main activity. How do I send the data that is in the json Response to the main activity. I can modify the initial lines of code and have the main activity started there, which would mean that i would extract the data in that class and just inject into the intent that starts the main activity, however I prefer maintaining the integrity of the code as I have written it and just using classes or methods.

Comment: Did you consider to `startActivityForResults`?

Comment: did not consider it.

Comment: You can also select your login activity as the first activity of your app since you say you don't even finish creating your MainActivity before calling your login activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use SubActivity concept.

Starts the child activity using `startActivityForResult` method. You can then return any results from the child activity to it's parent using `setResult`method.